# How do I test how customers use my Cocoa application?

Tags: cocoa, testing, feedback

I'm interested in finding out how customers use features in my Cocoa application.

I want to build up statistics on which features people use and how they use them, so that I can measure the value of features I'm implementing.

I'm building a desktop app to run on Snow Leopard.

This feedback of course will be opt-in and anonymous.

Does anyone know of any frameworks that have been developed that can achieve this without me having to write stuff from scratch?

Comment: It's a good thing to make the feedback anonymous but I would also make it opt-in only

Comment: That's what I meant by "off by default".

Comment: I'm selling a commercial software and I rolled my own solution to track that. I actually go much further than that because I can do really amazing things, like getting anonymous crash reports and when a new build fixes that particular bug, every customer affected by that bug gets the news that a new build is out (but the other customers, unaffected, don't get the notification). But SO isn't really a place where author of commercial Desktop software hang out... So I'm not holding my breath on having a great answer here to this question.

Comment: btw, my software only makes sense when there's an Internet connection and it's a *requirement*. There's a 30-days trial and if people don't like it, they can go buy inferior products from competitors ;)  Now, upon launch (and once in a while when running), the licence is checked for validity (once again, if people don't like that, they're free to not buy my software and go rant somewhere else).  When the licence check happens is when several infos are exchanged (usage statistics, crash/trace/log reports, etc.).

Comment: Ah.. Sorry must have misread the question.

Answer (score 1):

Might want to look into [Flurry Analytics](http://www.flurry.com/product/analytics/index.html). It's "free" and will track just about anything you're interested in.

Comment: Sorry, I should have stated I'm developing for the desktop. Flurry looks brilliant, but I think they only support iPhones.